# Does Oracle ADF Partial trigger submits the entire form?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a few UI components under `af:form` tag. If I apply partial trigger on any of the components by using its binding 
 `(AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(Componentbinding)` will it submits the entire form? Generally if it is a simple jquery ajax call we can get the only required data without doing form submit. And does partial page render also follows the entire ADF life cycle just to refresh only one component? Please explain?

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFUI/af_ppr.htm#ADFUI385):

> With ADF Faces, the feature that delivers the Ajax partial page render
>   behavior is called partial page rendering (PPR). During PPR, the JSF
>   page request lifecycle (including conversion and validation) is run
>   only for certain components on a page.

So:

1. The partial trigger functionality won't submit the entire form
2. The ADF lifecycle will be applied to the target (including its child components) and the [trigger component](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFUI/af_ppr.htm#ADFUI389)